# Can you test statistical significance in a single survey group by percentage change in answers?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a survey of nearly 900 people. I have found the percent that respond yes to various health related questions. I then separated the people by income of more than 25,000 dollars and less than 25,000 dollars and found the precent that indicated yes to the health questions. IT can be seen that people with an income of less than 25,000 dollars responded yes at a much lower percentage. Is there a way to show the percent is significantly different than the people with more than 25,000 dollars or the general response?